# Adjusting the heights of ggpubr derived pvalues manually with facetted plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Using the following code, I am making facetted plots with pvalues based on comparisons.

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggsci)

df <- melt(iris)
mycomparisons <- list(c("setosa", "versicolor"), c("setosa", "virginica"))

# Calculate the maximum value for each facetted plot to scale the axis limits
dmax = df  %>% group_by(variable) %>% 
  filter(value==max(value, na.rm=TRUE))

# Determine the number of replicates to use for modifying a dummy dataframe for scaling the y axis limits
num_reps <- df %>% group_by(Species,variable) %>% tally()
times <- sum(num_reps$n[c(1:length(unique(df$Species)))])

# Create a dummy dataframe to use for manually adjusting the y axis limits
dumdum <- df
dumdum$value <- c(rep(0, times = 0.5*times), rep(dmax$value[1]*1.2, times = 0.5*times),
                  rep(0, times = 0.5*times), rep(dmax$value[2]*1.2, times = 0.5*times),
                  rep(0, times = 0.5*times), rep(dmax$value[3]*1.2, times = 0.5*times),
                  rep(0, times = 0.5*times), rep(dmax$value[4]*1.2, times = 0.5*times))

ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x = Species, y = value, color = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NULL) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10)) +
  scale_color_jco() +
  facet_wrap(facets = "variable", scales = 'free_y') +
  geom_blank(data = dumdum) +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     aspect.ratio = 1, text = element_text(family="Helvetica")) +
  stat_compare_means(paired = FALSE, method = 't.test', label = "p.signif",
                     show.legend = FALSE, comparisons = mycomparisons)
```

[image]

However as you can see, the p values are getting cutoff on the y axis. I would like to be able to reposition them based on the height of the maximum value for a given comparison (i.e., the height of the comparison bar and pvalue should adjust automatically according to the height of the highest point within each comparison). Any help or pointers on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

So after almost 3 years here is your answer to this problem. I had the same issue and literally today as of May 4, 2020 `ggpubr` version `0.3.0` is released which allows for the inclusion of `vjust` in `stat_compare_means`. This allows to move those significance stars or p-values to be moved up or down.

```
     stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, 
                       label = "p.signif", 
                       vjust = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to increase the ratio of height vs width.